# Can I use a Adafruit Neopixel RGB STRIP with a Particle Photon?

Tags: led, particles, photon

I am not sure if the RGB strip below will work with the Particle Photon. At the RGB strip product description they mention the MCU (microcontroller) should have at least a processor faster than 8 MHz as well as a highly repeatable 100nS timing precision. I searched and found that we would be okay on the processing (STM32F205 120Mhz ARM Cortex M3) but I am completely unsure about the timing precision.

- What is time precision?
- Is the time precision of the Particle Photon enough?

Here is the link to the specific RGB strip for more details ([ADAFRUIT NEOPIXEL DIGITAL RGB LED STRIP - WHITE 60 LED](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1138))

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should be fine.  I have used my Particle Photon with an [8 LED strip](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-NeoPixel-Stick-8-x-WS2812-5050-RGB-LED-with-Integrated-Drivers-for-duino-and/32514106266.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.bxDXc6) and not had any issues.  There is a NeoPixel Library available for the photon as well.